# SQLAlchemy ORM complex joining Self-referential table

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm looking for some help in creating a database query - I'm looking to get the latest version of `Implementation` along with a `Base`. Both `Implementation` and `Base` have a `version`, and an `Implementation` can be created from a `Base`. When you create a `Implementation`, it `inherits the version` from `Base`. Subsequent increments to `Implementation`s do not impact `Base`, but vice-versa when an instance of `Base` is changed, I want to create a ORM query to get both the latest `Implementation` and the latest `Base` corresponding to it.

Expected return is something along the lines of

```py
>>> results
[ (<Base 4>, <Implementation 5>), ( ... ) ]
```

i.e. a list of tuples with the latest base and the current implementation.

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+---+------+--------+--------+--------+
| id| type | base_id| version| tracker|
+---+------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1|  base|    null|       1|   uuid |
|  4|  base|    null|       2|   uuid |
|  7|  impl|       1|       1|   uuid |
| 13|  impl|       1|       3|   uuid |
```

In this case, these rows are tied using the same uuid in the `tracker` row. The implementations also have other auxiliary data to uniquely identify where they are implemented. moreover, the implementation with id 13 is behind the base search corresponding to it, since there's a `Base` (id 4) with a higher version than the `implemented.base_id`s corresponding version (Base with id 1 has version 1). In this case, the expected return values are the rows/ objects corresponding to `4` and `13` (latest base with this uuid thats greater than the base_id of the implementation) and 13 ( the latest impl for this tracker )

I've gotten as far as the following:

```py
>>> sq1 = db.session.query(Base.id, Base.tracker, func.max(Base.version).label('max')).group_by(Base.tracker, Base.id).subquery("sub1")
>>> sq2 = db.session.query(Implementation, Implementation.base_id, Implemented.tracker).join(sq1, and_(Implementation.tracker == sq1.c.tracker, Base.version == sq1.c.max))
>>> b_alias = aliased(Base)
>>> results = sq.join(b_alias).filter(b_alias.version == sq1.c.max).all()
[]
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful. I've been working on this for a while now without luck, and I don't know how to get unstuck..